# WPF: How to apply data template for items in ItemsControl if items are strings?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, datatemplate

The `ItemsControl` defined below is filled with `string[] WeekDays`. The `DataTemplate` defined for `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` doesn't work, i.e. the week day items are not filled with red background. How do I fix this? Thanks.

```
 ...
<ItemsControl 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Margin="20,0,0,0" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WeekDays}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <UniformGrid Rows="1" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Background="Red" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
 ...
```

Note: `string[] WeekDays` is a dependency property of this control. I am not sure if this information might be relevant to finding the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the `TextBox`'s `Text` property to something in order it to work. So, since the data context of the data template is the string itself the binding should be like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="Red" />
</DataTemplate>
```